# Async with requests, how to get speed benefit

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Pretty new to Async so sorry for now able to phrase the question quite accurately.

I tried to use async following the example (https://pythonprogramming.net/asyncio-basics-intermediate-python-tutorial/) hoping to get some speed benefit of multiple requests.get() than doing it in a sync way.

```
import asyncio
import time
import requests

async def get_text(url):
    print(f"Load {url}")
    data = requests.get(url).text
    await asyncio.sleep(0.0001)
    print(f"Finished loading {url}")
    return data

async def main(name):
    tasks = [loop.create_task(get_text(n)) for n in name]
    await asyncio.wait(tasks)
    return tasks

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = ['https://www.nytimes.com', 'https://news.yahoo.com']
    s = time.perf_counter()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result = loop.run_until_complete(main(url))
    loop.close()
    e = time.perf_counter() - s
    print(f"Time takes: {e:0.2f}s")
```

But this apparently is just the same as running the two requests in sequence. Can you point out what I did wrong and how to do it properly in order to save time? I saw another example using ThreadPoolExecutor and loop.run_in_executor() but I am not sure how to incorporate it.

Best regards,

J

Comment: ``requests.get`` is a *synchronous* call. It doesn't benefit from ``async`` at all, and will block the entire event loop.

Comment: you’ll need to use the [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html?highlight=run_in_executor#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) method in order for the request to not be blocking

Answer (score 3):

`requests` does synchronous IO, so each call to `requests.get` is going to block the entire event loop. If you want async IO, use another library, such as [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable).

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve parallelism here by using Python multiprocessing.
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html
Takes a bit of read, but essentially this allows you to start new non-blocking processes, which would run in parallel, executing your code / functionality in parallel. so, sure, you can make parallel request calls. Make an attempt to convert your code to use multiprocessing, and there in the process should you need help, would be happy to help!